# JavaScript - find unique values in array of objects, with count and create a new array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filtering

I have an array of objects as below:

```
var arr =[
 {
  price:20,
  rule:a
 },
 {
  price:10,
  rule:b
 },
 {
  price:5,
  rule:a
 },
 {
  price:50,
  rule:b
 },
 {
  price:70,
  rule:b
 }
]
```

I want to extract an array of objects out of this as below:

```
var filteredArr = [
 {
  rule:a,
  countOfRule:2,
  minPriceForThisRule:5
 },
 {
  rule:b,
  countOfRule:3,
  minPriceForThisRule:10
 }
]
```

This means:

1) I want to create new array with no. of objects as unique no. of rules in first array "arr"

2) Need to count the unique rule repetition and add as property in new array objects - given as "countOfRule"

3) Find the minimum price for in a category of unique rule - given as "minPriceForThisRule"

I have read similar answers on SO and was able to get first 2 conditions only, and that too were not in the format as i need.

What I tried, referring to links on SO:

```
var ff = {},e;
for (var i = 0,l=arr.length; i < l; i++) {
   e = arr[i];
   ff[e.rule] = (ff[e.rule] || 0) + 1;
}
```

But this gives only a single object as

```
{
 a : 2,
 b: 3
}
```

Comment: Show us what you've done!

Comment: @NafiulIslam - Updated, what i tried.

Comment: @mplungjan - Sorry, I didn't get that. Could you please explain a little more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and `thisArg` optional parameter.

```js
var arr = [{"price":20,"rule":"a"},{"price":10,"rule":"b"},{"price":5,"rule":"a"},{"price":50,"rule":"b"},{"price":70,"rule":"b"}], 
    r = [];

arr.forEach(function(e) {
  if(!this[e.rule]) {
    this[e.rule] = {rule: e.rule, countOfRule: 0, minPriceForThisRule: e.price}
    r.push(this[e.rule]);
  }
  this[e.rule].countOfRule++;
  if(this[e.rule].minPriceForThisRule > e.price) this[e.rule].minPriceForThisRule = e.price;
}, {});

console.log(r)
```

Comment: Thanks, let me try this out.

Comment: Hey, just out of curiosity, how do you come up with such an answer and that too so fast. Building this logic and all. Would you have some recommendations for me on this, as to any javascript algo books, references etc. which could help me in such cases.

Comment: its just a standard pattern, which is not completely copied.

Comment: I learned to solve problems like this from smarter and more experienced developers then me here on SO, but some good places to learn also are http://eloquentjavascript.net/, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

Comment: Thanks again for the references. And yes, am also doing same, as far as SO goes  :-)

Comment: Hey, a follow up question on this. I accidentally missed the optional thisArg parameter, hence missed "{}" for this while implementing. I am working on Ember app and was calling this function from another one in ember component and was using computed properties. First time, I called this code (the one you provided here) it all worked fine, but as I changed another property which was being used as computed property in my code, this didnt work. It gave an empty array. So, I checked again and saw that I missed thisArg and then tried with this, it worked. Any idea, why is that so?

Answer (score 0):

I would use reduce.  Something like:

```
var reduced = arr.reduce(function(memo, obj){
   var rule = memo[obj.rule];
   rule.countOfRule++;
   if(!rule.minPriceForThisRule){
     rule.minPriceForThisRule = obj.price;
   } else{
     if(obj.price < rule.minPriceForThisRule){
       rule.minPriceForThisRule = obj.price;
     }
   }
   return memo;
}, map);
```

where the initial map looks like:

```
var map = {
  1: {
    rule: 1,
    countOfRule: 0,
    minPriceForThisRule: null      
  },
  2: {
    rule: 2,
    countOfRule: 0,
    minPriceForThisRule: null        
  }
}
```

Of course you could dynamically create the map if needed.

https://plnkr.co/edit/wLw3tEx2SMXmYE7yOEHg?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

This is how i would do this job,

```js
var arr =[
 {
  price:20,
  rule:"a"
 },
 {
  price:10,
  rule:"b"
 },
 {
  price:5,
  rule:"a"
 },
 {
  price:50,
  rule:"b"
 },
 {
  price:70,
  rule:"b"
 }
],
reduced = arr.reduce((p,c) => { var fo = p.find(f => f.rule == c.rule);
                                fo ? (fo.countOfRule++,
                                      fo.minPriceForThisRule > c.price && (fo.minPriceForThisRule = c.price))
                                   :  p.push({rule:c.rule, countOfRule:1, minPriceForThisRule: c.price});
                                return p;
                              },[]);
console.log(reduced);
```

Arrows might not work at IE or Safari. If that would be a problem please replace them with their conventional counterparts.